# grails i18n don't change the code attribute

Tags: grails, internationalization, grails-2.2

I'm new in Grails and try to use the i18n-plugin which is standardly integrated in the grails-framework (I use 2.2.1). I use the dynamic scaffolding and wondered that the labels of the variables of my domain model didn't changed with the values of the properties-file. That's why I tried to use the message-tag directly. But both ways don't work.
I didn't change any configuration. I take a simple view an add:

```
<g:message code=„my.test.de.label“ />
```

And I add in the message.properties and message_de.properties the following entry:

```
test.de.label=testDE
```

I opened the url with the "?lang=de" and without this parameter and nothing work. Also the labeling of the domain model via dynamic scollding didn't work.
If I this g:message-tag with a code which is standardly in the propertie-file everthing is fine. And I don't understand why my custom-label don't work.

**Question**: 
- Is there any configuration I have to do?
- Is there any code-error I made?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no configuration you need to do except creating new messages as you need.  I just created a new 2.2.1 project with a test domain class (`Notification`), then ran `generate all` for the new domain.

When I go to the list view for the new domain at `http://localhost:8080/TestApp/notifications/list?lang=de` I definitely see the German being used: `Notifications anlegen` and `Notifications Liste`

The only mistakes I can see in the direct use of the message tag are the commas `,,` instead of quotes `"` and the `my` in `my.test.de.label`.  This works for me:

```
//gsp
<g:message code="test.label" />

//messages_de.properties
test.label=testDe
```

You should probably NOT refer to the language in the actual message name - that sort of defeats the purpose.  Every language file should have the same 'name' for the message:

```
//messages_de.properties
default.button.create.label=Anlegen

//messages.properties
default.button.create.label=Create

//messages_es.properties
default.button.create.label=Crear
```

Then use in your GSP

```
<g:message code="default.button.create.label" />
```

That way the i18n system picks it out based on the language sent from the browser.

Comment: Hey, Thank's for help. I made an update to grails 2.2.2 and have a look at the commas and know everthing is running! :)